# Link images - XHTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I would like to link a small image, should I use XHTML or CSS ?

Comment: Define "link small image."  If you just need to link to an image, plain old HTML is all you need.  Is there something more you're looking to do?

Comment: Not sure what you meant, could you elaborate of what your trying to do? XHTML and CSS are two different things.

Comment: I don't understand this at all.

Comment: Small image is for example 30x30px. I can link image which is add trough <img> elemnt or I can add it like a background image. I am wondering is it a bad practice if I link background image.

Answer (score 5):

The difference between using css or xhtml comes down to *what the image is used for*. If it's a background, or merely for presentation purposes, use css. If it's a thumbnail, or similar, that links to a larger version of itself or serves a purpose on the page *other than* presentational, use an xhtml `img` element.

Presentational option:

```
a.imageLink {
    background: transparent url(path/to/image/relative/to/css/file.css) 0 0 no-repeat;
}

<a href="#" class="imageLink">Link to something</a>
```

Semantic 'useful within the xhtml file' option:

```
<a href="/path/to/larger/version.png">
    <img src="path/to/thumbnail.png" alt="this is a thumbnail of a larger, wonderful, image that you should go see!" />
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

To make an image hyperlink you should use XHTML and then style it with CSS

XHTML:

```
<a href="http://destination.com" >
  <img src="path/to/image.png" alt="Dont forget your alt tags" />
</a>
```

CSS:

```
a img{
  border: 0
}
```

CSS should only be used for images if they are not used for interaction, for example page background, borders, or backgrounds of buttons

```
background-image:url('bg.jpg');
```

Comment: ...don't forget to *close* your `alt` tags... =b

Comment: Thanks! Does that mean that it would be a bad practice if I link background image ? In some situations it is more convenient.. I mean when I can get good result with a <img>.

Comment: Nicol you can't link a CSS background image, only an element placed over the background. But yes many would consider this bad practice.

Comment: hypyhop thank you very much. That I wanted to know! So, I will not do that, if it is a bad practice. :) I just have to practice more with <img> tag to get what I need.

Answer (score 0):

You use CSS for an image if the image is part of your website's theme or template. Otherwise, you just use HTML for it.

Hope it helps.